# maven not packaging dependencies in jar

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies

**The problem**

I have a nested multiple module (correct terminology?) Maven project and the dependencies for one of the modules are not getting packaged with the jar when I `mvn clean package`

The project is actually a fork of something else that I didn't write, and somewhere along the line I broke the build process, but I can't seem to find out what I did.

The project structure is as follows:

- root

  - distribution (parent = root)
  - child1 (parent = root) **<-- dependencies not getting packaged for this one**
  - child2 (parent = root)

The poms are as follows (sorry for posting them all here, but I'm really not sure where to look):

**root**

```
<groupId>com.something</groupId>
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**distribution**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
</parent>

<artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**child1**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
</parent>

<artifactId>child1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    many dependencies here...
</dependencies>
```

**child2**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
</parent>

<artifactId>child2</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    many dependencies here...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**distribution.xml**

```
<id>package</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>..</directory>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        <includes>
            <include>README</include>
            <include>CHANGELOG</include>
            <include>LICENSE.txt</include>
            <include>NOTICE.txt</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../bin</directory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>../workloads</directory>
        <outputDirectory>workloads</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includeSubModules>true</includeSubModules>
        <sources>
            <includeModuleDirectory>true</includeModuleDirectory>

            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>.</directory>
                    <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
                    <includes>
                        <include>README</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>src/main/conf</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
                    <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    <directory>target</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                    <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

**Note: the code is on github, I'll gladly provide a link to the repository if someone has the time and desire to look at the real project!**

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is by design.  It's just the way jars work.  If you were to package dependencies in your jar, they won't work anyway.  The solution is to use the shade plugin to make an uberjar.  [Here's a tutorial on how.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

That [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) plugin can also do it, but it doesn't have as many features.  Either way, if you added that to your child1 pom, it would also package the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, but the original project DID NOT use that plugin, which makes me wonder how it actually worked...? (and it did/does work)

Comment: this is literally what `child1` looked like in the original project https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/core/pom.xml Note, that `maven-assembly-plugin` is not used... any idea how/why?

Comment: And does the child1 pom build standalone and include jars inside its jar?

Comment: in the original project calling `mvn clean package` at root (https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/pom.xml) results in the creation of `YCSB/core/target/core.jar`

Comment: And are any dependencies inside of it?